# Reshape list to shape with maximum row length

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

**Question**

I have an array:    `foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
And I was wondering the best way to get this array on the following shape:

```
[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
 [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
 [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
 [10.]]
```

How should I do ?
Thanks!

---

**What I currently do**

Since `foo` doesn't contains multiple of 3 elements using `numpy.reshape()` gives an error

```
import numpy as np
np.reshape(foo,(-1,3))
```

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (3)

So I need to force my array to contain multiple of 3 elements, either by dropping some (but I lose some data):

```
_foo = np.reshape(foo[:len(foo)-len(foo)%3],(-1,3))

print(_foo)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Or by extending with `nan`:

```
if len(foo)%3 != 0:
    foo.extend([np.nan]*((len(foo)%3)+1))

_foo = np.reshape(foo,(-1,3))
print(_foo)
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9.]
 [10. nan nan]]
```

---

**Notes**

- @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ recommendation is rather to work with full arrays instead (padding with `nan` or `0` for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@NedBatchelder's chunk generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/9209546) (upvote there).

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

list(chunks(lst, 3))

# [[1, 2, 3],
#  [4, 5, 6],
#  [7, 8, 9],
#  [10]]
```

Comment: Note that this only works for lists, arrays, etc. that are indexable! If you want something that works for generators too, Jinja2's batch filter is adaptable to your uses. https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/filters.py#L737-L765